# Does engineering undergrad performance matter for masters in management admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, career-path, engineering, management

In Masters in Management (MSc Mgmt/MIM) admissions, how much weight is generally given by the Adcom to the applicant's undergrad performance, especially if it's an unrelated one like engineering?

Does it have any bearing if the applicant's undergrad performance is poor but his other credentials are excellent?

What kind of credentials should such an applicant aim to acquire before applying (Other than the GMAT, TOEFL, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll speak from my own experience.

I had only a 2.9 GPA in my major, Economics. But I had a 3.5 overall.

What may have helped me was my GMAT score (over 750). In any event, I got into several top level MBA programs, including the one of my choice.

It helps to work a year or two before applying to an MBA program. A "gap year" (or more) is probably more valuable for this degree than for other graduate degrees.

Comment: Thanks Tom! But I'm referring to MiM/MSc Mgmt here, which are courses meant for candidates with little or no experience. In fact, some of them don't accept candidates with more than 1 year of experience.

Answer (score 0):

The engineering major is good in a way since they know you can handle MBA math.  But they won't really cut you much slack for poor performance or say it is irrelevant.  What is relevant is that you had a chance to get good grades and didn't.  They are looking for people who excel in whatever they do (engineering, economics, literature, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

Your undergraduate GPA is important for MIM because it is one of criteria where the admission team can evaluate your profile.
However the damages done by a low GPA can balanced by a high GMAT score, internships and a strong SOP.
I've also come to understand that it helps if your country of origin is not highly represented in the college of your choice (disadvantage to Indians).